# SQL WITH Clause and OR operator

Tags: sql, oracle, common-table-expression, or-operator

I am trying to fetch some records based on some conditions as given below -

```
WITH temp_data AS(SELECT t1.acc_name,t1.f_data,t1.EXPIRY_DATE,t1.f_days
            FROM t1_table t1, t2_table t2 where 
            t1.acc_name = t2.acc_name
            AND t2.FLAG = 2)            
SELECT tmp_data.acc_name 
FROM    temp_data tmp_data ,t3_table t3  where
( tmp_data.f_data = 'N' AND tmp_data.EXPIRY_DATE <= SYSDATE)
OR 
( tmp_data.f_data = 'Y' AND tmp_data.acc_name =  t3.acc_name 
              AND
              (
                (t3.f_interval_period <>-1 AND t3.f_DATE <= SYSDATE)
              OR (t3.f_interval_period =-1 AND  t3.f_DATE+t1.f_days <= SYSDATE)
              ))
```

When  tmp_data.f_data = 'N' AND tmp_data.EXPIRY_DATE <= SYSDATE condition satisfies , I am getting repetitive 180 records for 1 account name(e.g acc_name1 180 times) , when I am running the 'N' and 'Y' conditions separately one by one using with clause I get correct result(e.g. acc_name1 only once), for e.g

```
  WITH temp_data AS(SELECT t1.acc_name,t1.f_data,t1.EXPIRY_DATE,t1.f_days
                    FROM t1_table t1, t2_table t2 where 
                    t1.acc_name = t2.acc_name
                    AND t2.FLAG = 2)            
        SELECT tmp_data.acc_name 
        FROM    temp_data tmp_data  where
        ( tmp_data.f_data = 'N' AND tmp_data.EXPIRY_DATE <= SYSDATE)
```

==> this is without the addition of t3_table and gives only 1 account name and works fine,
but merging these two (tmp_data.f_data  = 'N' , 'Y')with OR , I  am not getting expected result and same account_number gets repeated multiple times.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you are missing the join condition, which I guess is `tmp_data.acc_name =  t3.acc_name`  for 'N' condition. So, when you combine the results you might get cartesian product of tmp_data and t3 datasets which is blowing your result.
Just a guess, you have to change somehow like that:

```sql
....
FROM   temp_data tmp_data, t3_table t3
where
   tmp_data.acc_name =  t3.acc_name and
   (
      ( tmp_data.f_data = 'N' AND tmp_data.EXPIRY_DATE <= SYSDATE)
      OR 
      (
        tmp_data.f_data = 'Y'
        AND
        (
           (t3.f_interval_period <> -1 AND  t3.f_DATE <= SYSDATE)
           OR
           (t3.f_interval_period =  -1 AND  t3.f_DATE + t1.f_days <= SYSDATE)
        )
      )
   )
```

Update 1: Thinking about left outer join, if I remember it correctly in Oracle `(+)` was used

```sql
....
FROM   temp_data tmp_data, t3_table t3
where
   tmp_data.acc_name =  t3.acc_name (+) and
   (
      ( tmp_data.f_data = 'N' AND tmp_data.EXPIRY_DATE <= SYSDATE)
      OR 
      (
        tmp_data.f_data = 'Y' and t3.acc_name is not null
        AND
        (
           (t3.f_interval_period <> -1 AND  t3.f_DATE <= SYSDATE)
           OR
           (t3.f_interval_period =  -1 AND  t3.f_DATE + t1.f_days <= SYSDATE)
        )
      )
   )
```

Take attention where you require the acc_name, specify conditon `t3.acc_name is not null`

Update 2: If your version of Oracle supports join keyword, most probably it does

```sql
WITH temp_data AS(SELECT t1.acc_name,t1.f_data,t1.EXPIRY_DATE,t1.f_days
            FROM t1_table t1 inner join t2_table t2 on t1.acc_name = t2.acc_name
            where  t2.FLAG = 2)            
SELECT tmp_data.acc_name 
FROM    temp_data tmp_data left join t3_table t3  on tmp_data.acc_name =  t3.acc_name 
where
( tmp_data.f_data = 'N' AND tmp_data.EXPIRY_DATE <= SYSDATE)
OR 
( tmp_data.f_data = 'Y' AND t3.acc_name is not null
              AND
              (
                (t3.f_interval_period <>-1 AND t3.f_DATE <= SYSDATE)
              OR (t3.f_interval_period =-1 AND  t3.f_DATE+t1.f_days <= SYSDATE)
              ))
```

Comment: Yes , this is the issue exactly , but I need that t3_table condition only in 'Y' not with 'N'

Comment: You need the join condition to be specified correctly, otherwise for each record in one table you will get full set of records in the other. That is cartesian product. Otherwise you will have to make two separate queries and combine them by ```union``` or ```union all```

Comment: Union All I had tried , its repetition of  - SELECT t1.acc_name,t1.f_data,t1.EXPIRY_DATE,t1.f_days
            FROM t1_table t1, t2_table t2 where 
            t1.acc_name = t2.acc_name
            AND t2.FLAG = 2, twice ,so needed to write with WITH clause

Comment: So, I am thinking, you need a query which in a case follows the join, and in the other it should break the join? I am thinking about outer joins now.

Comment: @galaxy0208 Please see the response again, update 2 if your version of Oracle supports the join keyword, and update 1 if doesn't support